# Certain js file not loading only in Internet Explorer Browser AND debugger

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a project that uses angular JavaScript controllers to populate fields. One particular page, members.cshtml, does not load on IE 11 even though it works fine on Chrome and Firefox.

Then looking at the debugger the file is not loading in IE:
[image]

But it loads in fine on other browsers:

[image]

I ran the file through jshint.com and and it said everything was fine with a few warnings.

Why is this file not loading and how do I get it to load?

Edit, I have found the error is on this line:

```
var index = $scope.allContracts.findIndex(attr => attr.CONT_ORDNO === contract.CONT_ORDNO);
```

I get a warning:    'arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6').

Does IE11 not accept this syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE does not support es6 syntax for now. https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Sometimes syntactical errors in JS causes it not load on IE. You can use babel or typescript compiler to transpile it to es5.